# How to map db columns to NHibernate xml file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I am new to NHibernate and MVC too.

I have a model class which contains properties like

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Full Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email Id")]
    public string EailID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 1)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

I have created xml mapping file for this model is like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   auto-import="true" assembly="EventMgnt" namespace="EventMgnt.Models">
  <class name="EventMgnt.Models.RegisterViewModel" table="tblUser" dynamic-update="true" >
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="Id" column="Id" type="int">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <property name="EmailID" />
    <property name="Password" />
    <property name="ConfirmPassword" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And i am getting `Could not compile the mapping document` error. Now I have few questions that,

1. Is it neccessary to write all properties which are available in model class in Nhibernate xml mapping file?
2. What if i do not have 1 column in database of **confirm password**?

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: You should take a look at "3 layer architecture". Its not a good approach to use your ViewModel as entity. The name already states it, it is for views, not for data persistence. And as small hint: you can use FluentNhibernate to map your entities. Its much easier to handle than .hbm files.

Comment: This is nice suggestion, helped me for my another task. Thank you. @Rabban

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No not required
2. You need to add database column matching properties only. You can ignore confirm password property
   Most probably this error is related to NHibernate  mapping assembly or namespace